# Getting grub rescue every time after using windows

Tags: dual-boot, grub2, partitioning, windows-8, grubrescue

I have Ubuntu 14.04 installed alongside Windows 8.1 and they've been living happily next to each other until a recent Windows update. Now every time I use Windows and restart to boot to Ubuntu I get the grub rescue command line. I have done boot repair several times using the live disk to get GRUB back and that way I can boot to Ubuntu, but if I switch to Windows and back its grub rescue again.

My pc also displays weird behavior: if I get the grub rescue prompt, I can restart my PC and go to the BIOS config screen, do literally nothing and exit and GRUB is back running again.

Here is my fdisk output:

```
    Disk /dev/sdb: 500.1 GB, 500107862016 bytes
    255 heads, 63 sectors/track, 60801 cylinders, total 976773168 sectors
    Units = sectors of 1 * 512 = 512 bytes
    Sector size (logical/physical): 512 bytes / 4096 bytes
    I/O size (minimum/optimal): 4096 bytes / 4096 bytes
    Disk identifier: 0x43f0837d

    Device Boot      Start         End      Blocks   Id  System
    /dev/sdb1   *        2048      411647      204800    7  HPFS/NTFS/exFAT
    /dev/sdb2          411648   812929023   406258688    7  HPFS/NTFS/exFAT
    /dev/sdb3       935811072   976361471    20275200   12  Compaq diagnostics
    /dev/sdb4       812931070   935811071    61440001    5  Extended
    Partition 4 does not start on physical sector boundary.
    /dev/sdb5       812931072   820742143     3905536   82  Linux swap / Solaris
    /dev/sdb6       820744192   935811071    57533440   83  Linux

    Partition table entries are not in disk order
```

Any ideas?